# Not correct positioning in python lists

Tags: python

I have a problem with list items positioning in python program.
I'm using python 2.7
This is my code:

```
MAX_DOWNLOADERS = 4
from threading import Lock
import time,random,unittest
from random import randrange

class Choker:
    def __init__(self,PeerManager,max_uploads,min_uploads=None):
        self.PM = PeerManager
        self.max_uploads = max_uploads
        if min_uploads == None:
            self.min_uploads = max_uploads
        else:
            self.min_uploads = min_uploads
        self._round = 0
        self.run = True
        self.lock = Lock()
    def _unchoke_peers(self):
        while self.run:
            self._rechoke()
            self.count += 1
            time.sleep(UNCHOKE_INTERVAL)
    def _rechoke(self):
        count = 0
        preferred = []
        if self._round % 3 == 0:
            for pos,peer in enumerate(self.PM.peers):
                if peer.am_choking and peer.peer_interested:
                    self.PM.peers = self.PM.peers[pos:] + self.PM.peers[:pos]
                    break
        for i in self.PM.peers:
            if not self._snubbed(i) and i.peer_interested:
                if self.PM.completed:
                    preferred.append((i.download_speed,i))
                else:
                    preferred.append((i.upload_speed,i))
        preferred.sort(reverse=True)
        print(len(preferred))
        del preferred[self.max_uploads-1:]
        preferred = [x[1] for x in preferred]
        print(len(preferred))
        hit = False
        for peer in self.PM.peers:
            if peer in preferred:
                peer.send_unchoke()
                print('unchoking peer in preferred')
                count += 1
                print('count += 1 in preferred')
            else:
                if count < self.min_uploads or not hit:
                    peer.send_unchoke()
                    print('unchoking peer in count < self.min_uploads')
                    if peer.peer_interested:
                        count += 1
                        hit = True
                        print('count += 1 in count < self.min_uploads')
                else:
                    peer.send_choke()
                    print('choking peer')
    def _snubbed(self, peer):
        if self.PM.completed:
            return False
        return peer.is_snubbed()
    def connection_made(self, peer,p=None):
        if p == None:
            p = randrange(-2, len(self.PM.peers) + 1)
        print(p)
        self.PM.insert(max(p, 0), peer)
        self._rechoke()
    def connection_lost(self, peer):
        self.PM.peers.remove(peer)
        if peer.peer_interested and not peer.am_choking:
            self._rechoke()
    def interested(self, peer):
        if not peer.am_choking:
            self._rechoke()
    def not_interested(self, peer):
        if not peer.am_choking:
            self._rechoke()


class PM:
    def __init__(self):
        self.peers = []
        self.completed = False
        self.lock = Lock()
    def insert(self,pos,elem):
        self.lock.acquire()
        self.peers.insert(pos,elem)
        self.lock.release()
    def remove(self,elem):
        self.peers.remove(elem)


class PeeR:
    def __init__(self,upload_speed=0):
        self.peer_interested = False
        self.am_choking = True
        self.is_seeder = False
        self.upload_speed = upload_speed
        self.download_speed = 0
        self.snubbed = False
    def send_choke(self):
        self.am_choking = True
    def send_unchoke(self):
        self.am_choking = False
    def is_snubbed(self):
        return self.snubbed
```

When i'm writing code located below:

```
pm = PM()
choker = Choker(pm,1)
c1 = PeeR()
c2 = PeeR(1)
c3 = PeeR(2)
c4 = PeeR(3)
choker.connection_made(c1)
choker.connection_made(c2,1)
choker.connection_made(c3,1)
choker.connection_made(c4,1)
```

in pm.peers ( this is a list ) position of the elements (c1,c2 ...) is not correct (e.g. c4 is not in position 1, c1 is not in position 0).
Why does it happen?
Please help me.

Comment: What is the expected order and what is the actual order you get? As I read it, the expected order should be `c1, c4, c3, c2`, is that correct?

Comment: Your code, as posted here, **does** put `c1` in position 0. I ran the code. `c2` through to `c4` are inserted at position 1 and shift to the right as more are inserted, so you end up with `c1, c4, c3, c2` and their positions are not shifted otherwise.

Comment: In other words, what do **you** see instead, and are you certain you posted all the code here?

Comment: You reorder your peers inside `rechoke`: `self.PM.peers = self.PM.peers[pos:] + self.PM.peers[:pos]`

Comment: @Hyperboreus: That's the point though; that code doesn't run with the state the peers start in. The code, as posted, won't trigger that line.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Then either there is black magic at work or relevant parts of the code are missing. I guess the former.

Comment: Relevant parts are missing; this is an (attempt at) a bittorrent client, I'd say.

Comment: @Hyperboreus Line that you mentioned above is just optimistic unchoking implementation(every 30 seconds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reduce your code to the relevant parts:

```
#! /usr/bin/python2.7

from random import randrange

class Choker:
    def __init__(self,PeerManager):
        self.PM = PeerManager
    def connection_made(self, peer,p=None):
        if p == None:
            p = randrange(-2, len(self.PM.peers) + 1)
        self.PM.insert(max(p, 0), peer)

class PM:
    def __init__(self):
        self.peers = []
    def insert(self,pos,elem):
        self.peers.insert(pos,elem)

pm = PM()
choker = Choker(pm)
c1, c2, c3, c4 = 'C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4'
choker.connection_made(c1)
choker.connection_made(c2,1)
choker.connection_made(c3,1)
choker.connection_made(c4,1)

print (pm.peers)
```

Now this yields the expected output (as I would expect it): `['C1', 'C4', 'C3', 'C2']`.

`C1` is inserted at position 0.
`C2` is inserted at position 1.
`C3` is inserted at position 1, moving `C2` to position 2.
`C4` is inserted at position 1, moving `C2` to position 3 and `C3` to position 2.

---

As Martijn pointed out: Remember that inside `rechoke` you reorder your list:

```
self.PM.peers = self.PM.peers[pos:] + self.PM.peers[:pos]
```

Comment: Which means that most likely the OP missed something in `_rechoke` where it'll reorder the peers..

Comment: You are right: `self.PM.peers = self.PM.peers[pos:] + self.PM.peers[:pos]` inside `rechoke`.

Comment: Oh, with strings it works,but with class objects it messes the position

Comment: Thanks!!! Problem was in _rechoke,because at __init__() self._round=0, and 0%3 is always 0!